# Why does this SPARQL query return a title?

Tags: rdf, sparql

I was looking for a SPARQL tutorial, but all I found was just queries and results - no descriptions. For example:

• Data:

```
<http://example.org/book/book1>
<http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title>
"SPARQL Tutorial" .
```

• Query:

```
SELECT ?title
WHERE { <http://example.org/book/book1>
<http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title>
?title . }
```

• Result:

```
title
"SPARQL Tutorial"
```

Can someone explain this example? Because in the data, I just see 2 URLs and some value. And in the query I just see `select ?title`, but I don't see any title in the data and so on...

Also, in this example there is just "data", but I thought that SPARQL works with RDF files. So can someone show me an RDF file to this example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to look at the data from a different perspective. Your data is just one triple of the form (subject, predicate, object). If you look at it in just one line it might be easier to understand:

```
<http://example.org/book/book1> <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/title> "SPARQL Tutorial" .
```

`../book1` is the subject, `../title` is the predicate and `"SPARQL Tutorial"` is the object.

Answer (score 0):

I really would like to recommend you reading Bob DuCharme's ["Learning SPARQL"](http://learningsparql.com/), since it doesn't only show you data, queries and result - it also explains everything in an easy understandable way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a (single) statement, saying "the title of book1 is 'SPARQL Tutorial'"; your query is a question "what is the title of book1?". So the result is the answer to your question: "SPARQL Tutorial".

If you save your data to a file, you have your RDF file, which conforms to the [Notation3](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Notation3), [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TeamSubmission/turtle/) and [N-Triples](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-testcases/#ntriples) specifications.